# How to send external form POST data through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a web form, simple HTML / PHP that works by itself but when it is passed onto the template page via the below AJAX call -- the post data is missing on submission. This HAS got to be a param I'm missing below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#toggle3').click(function(){
    var tog = $('.toggle');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/mysimplewebform.php',
        success: function (fields){
            tog.html(fields);
            tog.slideToggle(1000);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

The request is sent. And upon submission I receive email, everything but the selected post data via form is sent. Below is the PHP.

```
<?php
    $backwheel = $_POST['backwheel'];
    $frontwheel = $_POST['frontwheel'];
    $form_message = "backwheel:".$backwheel." frontwheel:".$frontwheel." \nMessage: ". " You just recieved a new custom order via your Customizer!"."\nFullCustomURL: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

  mail("email@gmail.com", "Your Website Something", $form_message, "From: Capn Ron (New Order!)" );

  if (isset($_POST['submit']))

    {   
echo "<script>
alert('Thanks for your Order!');
window.location.href='http://www.website.com';
</script>";       
    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you see in the console? What element is that?

Comment: Is `toggle3` the id of your form? Because when you call `$(this).serialize()`, the `this` refers to the DOM element with an id of `toggle3`.

Comment: That was a typo, I removed serialize it was a desperate recent attempt.

Comment: Well, you need to send something over the wire via the data parameter, otherwise it is expected that `$_POST` is empty.

Comment: Yes! That's what I figured, I'm unsure how to write that; I've tried data: data, I'm not entirely sure what AJAX requires, fairly new.

Comment: What do you specify as "template page"? If you have a php page 1 and send via AJAX to php page 2, then you have to redirect somehow at the same time to page 2???

Comment: No, template page is .html -- form handler page is .php that's it.

Comment: So how do you receive on the `html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing a param. From your code, #toggle3 appears to be button since the click event is bound to it. So, if you try to serialize it, it will certainly return nothing. You have to serialize the surrounding form which is easily achieved by using jQuery's `closest()` function; i.e.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#toggle3').click(function(){
    var tog = $('.toggle');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/mysimplewebform.php',
        data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
        success: function (fields){
            tog.html(fields);
            tog.slideToggle(1000);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Tleilax; this would go on form handler page or in AJAX?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an adapted version of your original code.

Comment: That's awesome! But unfortunately still the same result :(

Comment: Have you checked whether the data actually gets transmitted with either DevTools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox? In both tools you should be able to see the request in the networks tab.

If it's not transmitted, please provide the according HTML code for this javascript. If it is transmitted, you should check your php code that receives the request.

Comment: Thanks again, the only thing I'm seeing abnormal is it's showing jQuery 2.0 is generating a Request Method:GET. Everything else seems OK, form.php states POST status OK and pulls in mark-up; sends all but POST data.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. You could try replacing your `$.ajax` call with an equivalent `$.post` call: `$.post('/mysimpleform.php', $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function (fields) { ... });`

Comment: So! I think you are right, it appears the form is trying to submit with the onclick of the parent toggle. But the closet solution didn't work -- maybe I need to include that in the php handler as well or?