# form within AJAX jQuery toggle, submits at parent onClick not from submit button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Basically `mysimplewebform.php` form submits when the toggle is clicked, as opposed to after the form is loaded, used by user and SUBMITTED via submit button at form. Obviously I need to have form operate functionally; user fills it out, and clicks submit. I simply used AJAX to bring in the form on the template page. Now everytime toggle button is clicked 'Form is submitted with empty values' and then appears in the toggle. Making it pretty useless at this point, I have been struggling with this forever. I think this is a matter of toggling the `data:` below --

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#toggle3').click(function(){
        var tog = $('.toggle');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/mysimplewebform.php',
            data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(), // This was a recent suggestion
            success: function (fields){
                tog.html(fields);
                tog.slideToggle(1000);
            }
        });
      });
    });
```

Branched out from: [How to send external form POST data through AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537218/how-to-send-external-form-post-data-through-ajax)

Comment: You are just making a series of confusing questions. None of them really make sense. In all of them you talk about 'pulling in a form via ajax' but then show code that makes an ajax post request. I suggest you explain what you are trying to do in plain english, and we can go from there

Comment: why don't you register the submit() event rather than the onclick? That would be easier...

Comment: Thank you @user574632. It's very simple. .HTML webpage (acting as a template) > click a button > button expands toggle > AJAX pulls in web form within this alotted area > web form that is now present within toggle does not submit. Struggle has been to submit web form presented this way. Web form works standalone. Thanks for your candor.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you want to display an html form when a user clicks a button? In that case you can use the simplified jquery load method:

```
$('#yourbutton').click(function(){
    $('#somediv').load('/mysimplewebform.php');
});
```

I know this doesnt handle your toggle requirement, but i dont think that is where you are having issues.

Now onto the php. I dont know exactly what should be in mysimplewebform so heres an example

```
if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
    //we have a post request, lets process it

    echo 'hello'.$_POST['fname'];
}?>

<form action="absolute/path/to/mysimplewebform.php" method="post" id="mysimplewebform">
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Notice the action is an absolute path to the file, because a relative path will be wrong if the form is loaded into another page via ajax.

Now when this form is submitted, the browser will be redirected to mysimplewebform.php.

I expect you want to stay on the same page, in which case you could submit the form via ajax:

```
$('#mysimplewebform').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();//stop normal redirecting submit
    $.post( $(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
          $('#somediv').html(data)
    });
```

This replaces the whole form in the dom with the output, so the hello message would be displayed.

All of the above is an attempt to help you understand where you have been going wrong in your attempts. It is not the best solution to your overall problem - i would separate the html form and processing into seperate files for a start, but it should be familiar to you.

Comment: Thanks for writing all of that -- I've deleted the first question; but there I discussed how I tried most of what you wrote above and came to the conclusion that the submit firing with toggle onClick and the post values not going through the AJAX include -- is where it's failing (keeping current code). I'm currently trying to figure it out without rewriting everything, which I will soon resort too eventually without solution. I haven't taken that leap because form partially submits as is, keeping inspiration of ultimate solution.